# Unknown column 'W1000000115031' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql

I have a problem which I cant fix. There are many posts regarding this but being someone who don't know PHP or SQL, I cant seem to pinpoint to the part that is giving me this error.

Well, I am using a script by [XQTO](http://www.xqto.com/tablemanager.php) installed [here](http://www.keretapi.com/lc/tm_customer.php). I can add and delete records without any issues but i keep getting this error whenever I click on edit and save:

> Unknown column 'W1000000115031' in 'where clause'

```
UPDATE consignments SET WaybillNo = 'W1000000115031', DateReceived = '2015-07-24', ConsigneeName = 'Jason Devadason', Status1 = 'Test2', Status2 = 'Test', Status3 = 'Test', Status4 = 'Test', Status5 = '', Status6 = '', date_delivered = '2015-07-27' WHERE WaybillNo = W1000000115031
```

From what I read in this forum, I need to edit something to get rid of this error but I just don't know where. I know little to nothing when it comes to PHP or SQL.

This is the `tablemanager.php` codes:
www.keretapi.com/lc/tablemanagertxt.txt  ( not sure how to enter codes here)

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you need to put string-literal quotes around the literal value in where clause : `WHERE WaybillNo = 'W1000000115031'`

Comment: You should use syntax highlighting when debugging queries. It answers your question instantly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use single quotes arround the value in `WHERE` clause:

```
 ... WHERE WaybillNo = 'W1000000115031'
```

Answer (score 0):

Put single quote on given value in where clause.

Change FROM

```
WHERE WaybillNo = W1000000115031
```

To

```
WHERE WaybillNo = 'W1000000115031'
```

Answer (score 0):

you forget quotes for value in **WHERE** clause.

Use below query:

```
 UPDATE consignments SET WaybillNo = 'W1000000115031', DateReceived = '2015-07-24', 
 ConsigneeName = 'Jason Devadason', Status1 = 'Test2', Status2 = 'Test', Status3 = 'Test',
 Status4 = 'Test', Status5 = '', Status6 = '', date_delivered = '2015-07-27'
 WHERE WaybillNo = "W1000000115031"
```

Comment: May i know where in the tablemanager.php can i change this. In the tablemanager.php, WaybillNo is known as primarykey. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Need to change:

```
WHERE WaybillNo = W1000000115031
```

To:

```
WHERE WaybillNo = 'W1000000115031';
```

**Reason**:

"W1000000115031" is not valid in the context where it is used. Because it is its value not a column, e.g. `where WaybillNo.id = fk.id;` is valid because both resolve to value and `fk` is and `WaybillNo` should be defined before use

Comment: Thanks for the replies. May i know where in the tablemanager.php can i change this. In the tablemanager.php, WaybillNo is known as primarykey. Thanks.

Comment: Glad! But here we say thanks by voting up and accepting an answer.

Comment: Woops, will do that. Thanks.